# Cron scheduling shell command returns 'app' error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cron

I'm trying to make use of [this module](https://github.com/liebig/cron) in Laravel 4.2.

Following all the steps, I'm at the last one, where running `* * * * * php artisan cron:run` (while in the root of my project) yields the error:

```
No command 'app' found, but there are 17 similar ones
app: command not found
```

In an earlier step of the guide `php artisan migrate` worked fine, so I am wondering where does the problem come from.

Comment: facing same issue. please suggest some solutions..